# Ajax:AutoCompleteExtender 500 Error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

Im using .NET version 4.0 and it seems like when I try to use webservice from use

Ajax:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server"

and the webmethod is :

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getstuff(string prefixText, int count)
{
    List<test> projects = new List<test>();
    string searchText = prefixText;
    projects.Add(new test { Age=123, Name="Hanna"});
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(projects);
    //return projects.ToArray();

}
```

I'm getting the famouse error from fiddler

> System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid:
>   application/json; charset=UTF-8.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

What can be the problem?
Thanks in advanced for any kind of help

Comment: You send bad request to WS. Show JS code.

Comment: yeah i figured that too from the error in fiddler but how to i change that

Comment: inside the  <Ajax:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server"
           ID="aceProjekt"
           TargetControlID="tbForening"
           ServiceMethod="getstuff"
           ServicePath="/WebServices/ats.asmx"     
           MinimumPrefixLength="3"
           CompletionSetCount="20"
           CompletionInterval="1000"
           UseContextKey="false" 
           EnableCaching="false"/>